# How to pass value from html to xpath expression in php?

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

HTML -

```
<form action="http://192.168.64.2/file.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" id="venue" name="venue" />
```

XML -

```
<a>
<a1>
<author pid = "123"> </author>
<book>Book1</book>
</a1>
<a2>
<editor pid = "123"> </editor>
<book>Book2</book>
</a2>
</a>
```

Xpath in PHP -

```
<?php
$venue = $_GET['venue'];
$abc= new DomDocument();
$abc -> load("file.xml");
        $xpath = new DOMXPath($abc);
$xyz = $xpath -> evaluate ("count(//book[.='$venue'] and //author[@pid='123'] and //editor[@pid='123'] [parent::a1 or parent::a2] )");
echo $xyz;
?>
```

If the value entered in the form in HTML is found in the XML "book" tag and author id or editor id = 123 then I want to find count of book element. I am trying this but not getting the count and getting an error. Please help.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *I want to find count of that*, a count of what?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to use single quotes around the variable ? `$xyz = $xpath -> evaluate("//book[.='$venue'][parent::a1 or parent::a2]")` So, if you want to count the number of book elements which respect the condition of your form `$xpath -> evaluate("count(//book[.='$venue'][parent::a1 or parent::a2])")`

Comment: @E.Wiest aaah...it worked...Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: @E.Wiest Can you please help? I have modified my question now.

Answer (score 0):

To count the book elements which respect your conditions (value of the book element = value of the form, and attribute  value of the preceding author or editor elements = 123), use this expression :

```
count(//book[.='$venue'][preceding-sibling::editor[@pid='123'] or preceding-sibling::author[@pid='123']])
```